# python - changing variable values in different modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have four variables that are required to be changed in specific modules and read in specific modules. To clarify, these modules are '`health`', '`max_health`, '`attack`' and '`gold`'.

The gold is meant to increase whenever an enemy is defeated in each of the application's three levels and reduced when a piece of armor/a weapon is bought in the armory module, the health is meant to reduce when attacked by an enemy and restored in the hospital module, the max_health is dependent on which armor has been equipped in the armory module and the same applies to the attack and which weapon has been equipped.

The problem is that the set values are always taken from a module where I have stored each of the variables along with the functions of the applications.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way of initially taking the value from each of the variables when the application first launches and then as the application goes on, the values can be changed and read in the modules as described above.

Any feedback would be widely appreciated.

EDIT: The variables are globalised and established in StoreData as follows:

```
global max_health
global health
global attack
global gold

max_health = 100
health = 100
attack = 5
gold = 0
```

These variables are then imported into each module as follows:

```
from PKG.StoreData import hub_from_level1_travel, max_health, attack, gold, health

from PKG.StoreData import health, max_health, attack, gold, hub_from_level2_travel

from PKG.StoreData import health, max_health, attack, gold, hub_from_level3_travel

from PKG.StoreData import hospital_heal, hub_from_hospital_travel, max_health, health, gold, attack

from PKG.StoreData import hospital_travel, armoury_travel, level1_start, level2_start, level3_start, exit, health, max_health, attack, gold

from PKG.StoreData import hub_from_armoury_travel, max_health, health, gold, attack
```

The values for the variables are changed as initially described but the changes do not replace the set values shown in StoreData. Instead, the values are taken from StoreData when any module that isn't StoreData is in use and takes the initially set values instead. I can't wrap my head around any potential fixes for this issue so feedback would be eternally grateful at this moment.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

First, your global statements are pointless. If those variables are defined at module level, they are already global.

Secondly, to fix your issue you should import the module, not the variables. You can then read and set them via that module reference:

```
from PKG import StoreData

StoreData.hub_from_level1_travel = 'foo'
```

Alternatively, you could introduce another namespace within StoreData to set your variables on - eg a class.

Comment: Testing out that answer has given me: NameError: name 'health' is not defined. I believe that my functions are an issue with this answer since my functions pass parameters.

Comment: Removing the parameters means that certain names can't be defined.

Comment: Obviously, you need to read your attributes via StoreData as well.

Comment: I do not understand?